# Where and Right/Left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code in SQL Server, when I use my filter on `INNER JOIN` condition, right join works fine, but if I change its position and create a where, it stops to working, my question is every time that I use RIGHT or LEFT JOIN I can't use `WHERE`?

```
SELECT pcm.clacta,
       pcm.descta,
       pcm.ctared,
       SUM(mcp.vlrliq)
  FROM e501tcp tcp 
 INNER JOIN e501mcp mcp ON mcp.codemp = tcp.codemp
                       AND mcp.codfil = tcp.codfil
                       AND mcp.numtit = tcp.numtit
                       AND mcp.codtpt = tcp.codtpt
                       AND mcp.codfor = tcp.codfor 
 RIGHT JOIN (SELECT pcm.clacta,
                    pcm.descta,
                    pcm.ctared
               FROM e043pcm pcm 
              WHERE pcm.codmpc = 700) pcm ON pcm.ctared = tcp.ctafin    
 WHERE tcp.codfil = 1
   AND tcp.numtit = '1/01' 
 GROUP BY pcm.clacta,
          pcm.descta,
          pcm.ctared
 ORDER BY pcm.clacta;
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Unexpected data? No data? "If I change its postion" what did you change?

Comment: The solution to your problem is probably to move the conditions in the outer `WHERE` clause into one of the `ON` clauses.  But without seeing data, and what you expect here, I can't be certain.

Comment: It depends on which table you are trying to filter. With a left or right join, rows with no match will have `null` for column values. This means you may need to account for `null` values in your `where` clauses, or more simply move them to the `on` condition of the join. --aside: `right join`s are a pain, reading code with `left join`s is easier for everyone I've known.

Comment: I moved "where" to "on"

Comment: I didn't see any error

Answer (score 1):

I am not a fan of `RIGHT JOIN`. I think `LEFT JOIN`s are much clearer (keep everything in the **first** table rather than the **last** table). In any case, your problem is that the `WHERE` clause is undoing the `RIGHT JOIN`.

I would write this as:

```
SELECT pcm.clacta,
       pcm.descta,
       pcm.ctared,
       SUM(mcp.vlrliq)
FROM e043pcm pcm LEFT JOIN
     e501tcp tcp 
     ON pcm.ctared = tcp.ctafin AND
        tcp.codfil = 1 AND
        tcp.numtit = '1/01' LEFT JOIN
     e501mcp mcp
     ON mcp.codemp = tcp.codemp AND
        mcp.codfil = tcp.codfil AND
        mcp.numtit = tcp.numtit AND
        mcp.codtpt = tcp.codtpt AND
        mcp.codfor = tcp.codfor 
 WHERE pcm.codmpc = 700
 GROUP BY pcm.clacta, pcm.descta, pcm.ctared
 ORDER BY pcm.clacta;
```

Notes:

- The condition on `pcm` can be in the `WHERE` clause.
- No subquery is needed for `pcm`.
- The original `WHERE` conditions are now in the `ON` clause.
- The order of the `JOIN`s is switched around, with the second conditions switched to a `LEFT JOIN`.

Also, this logic is not *exactly* the same as yours.  There are subtle differences based when there are matches in 2 of the 3 tables.  I doubt that this makes a difference for the results that you want.

Comment: This solution, gave me the same result as I expected, had done something very similar, using the table e043pcm as the main table, but in case it was not strong entity in the relationship then I re-queried the query, but why did it happen? if I was filtering my main table, I already used that same query in oracle and the result was what I expected, I did not have that problem.

Comment: Every filter that I'll make will be on e501tcp

Comment: Why    where    is undoing    right join     , if I don't use any column on table that is in    right join

Comment: @ThiagoSapucaia . . . The first two tables are involved in the `right join` -- those are the tables where the `NULL` values are added onto unmatched rows.

Comment: @ThiagoSapucaia `WHERE` applies to the intermediate rowset defined by the joins, so it filters out the rows with `NULL`s that the join synthesises, whereas `ON` defines which rows to synthesise `NULL`s for